# Is AlarmManager based on the device's current time?

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, android-date

I have an app that has a separate (so to speak).. `Clock` from the device's system clock. From that Clock, I need to create an alarm if that clock reaches a specific time. Now I am using `AlarmManager` and `PendingIntent` to create an alarm but it only takes the `long triggerAtMillis` as argument. Is this based on the device's system clock?

As per the `javadocs` of `AlarmManager.setRepeating()`:

```
 * @param triggerAtMillis time in milliseconds that the alarm should first
 * go off, using the appropriate clock (depending on the alarm type).
```

So what does `appropriate clock` means?

Comment: Yep it is based on your device time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the `AlarmManager` works on the device time, the time to trigger the alarm is provided by you.

So you can can calculate the difference between your custom clock and the device clock and then pass the time accordingly to the `AlarmManager`.

You can try something like this

**Step 1** Get the current time of device clock and your clock and subtract them to get the difference

**Step 2** With the difference, you can now calculate the device time according to your clock time

**Step 3** Now set the `AlarmManager` according to that time which is the device time equivalent of your custom clock time.

Although this is a work-around, but this is what I could think of.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html)

> There are two general clock types for alarms: "elapsed real time" and "real time clock" (RTC). Elapsed real time uses the "time since system boot" as a reference, and real time clock uses UTC (wall clock) time. This means that elapsed real time is suited to setting an alarm based on the passage of time (for example, an alarm that fires every 30 seconds) since it isn't affected by time zone/locale. The real time clock type is better suited for alarms that are dependent on current locale.

The time is dependent on Current local, as the suer change the local setting, it would effect your alarm too.
Also you can use RTC methode based on your wish